# Browse Android Internal Storage - Afterwards

Tags: java, android, internal-storage

This is a simple question: is there a way to browse files stored in an app specific Android App utilising [Internal Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) the trick is that I think I need to do this via a 3rd party app.

Why would I want to do this? Well. I have versions of the software that I deliver and a previous version had a bug whereby saved PDF's (generated in the APP on the device) were not getting delivered under all circumstances - now - I have fixed the bug, and introduced a failsafe to get the files off a NEW installation going forward, but I now have a BIG problem because if I implement a NEW APP it will by default UNINSTALL all the internal storage files- therby loosing the associated data - which I need

Is there a way round this?

My idea was to maybe create a 2nd app that allows the browsing / emailing of files of the internal storage - get the files off the phone - then uninstall all you like

Comment: You may need root permission to browse other app specific files ...

Comment: An app cannot access another app's internal files without having root permissions. That's why they're called internal files. What I don't understand is why you'll be losing existing PDF files - if you just upgrade the existing app, it will be able to access the existing files, and then you can deliver them.

Comment: no, the apk won't install without manual uninstall which trashes the data

Comment: Why is that? Any solution I can think of for your situation consists of upgrading the existing app, while preserving the existing data. Why would this require an uninstall?

Comment: because the apk's are emailed to the device or downloaded from a log in only website and they have always required uninstall - that's how android made it

Comment: Not sure what you mean - apps are upgradable, as long as the new app uses the same package name and the same keystore. Anyway, only that same application is guaranteed to have the ability to access its internal files. Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: it's ok, it's OT but I build the apk on the fly (logo/name/server changes) using a pretty clever JIT builder run via PHP so it always looks/is-named/points-to-right-server for the customer at their installation, so the Android portion of the system downloads from the website.. I think the name changing using the ant build.xml is causing it to overwrite

Comment: just checked - you are right, this is a by-product of the `JIT apk` manufacture: namely that as of now all subsequent `apks` made using `ant` are indeed merely upgrading and keeping the `internal storage`, the problem is that the other `apks` were built without the `ant keystore` so don't have the same signature etc etc.. just to confirm using the same keystore on build DOES work to allow you to use the same `private internal storage` indefinately